# strange error/SIGABRT thread 1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[image: StoryBoard]

A couple of strange errors appeared in my code after I made a duplicate of the folder, I deleted the duplicate but I have some **errors** remaining..

> Thread 1 SIGABRT error when running, build completes but doesn't load.
>   error is on the line with class AppDelegate

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
```

The other error lies in the image.

thanks for the help.[image: Build Failed 1 error]

[image: error after adding exception breakpoint]

[image: Console]

Comment: Perhaps the originals are still referenced somehow. Try removing them and add them back

Answer (score 0):

1. When you delete a file from Xcode, you should choose "Move to Trash".You can just add it to Xcode again, and delete it use "Move to Trash".
2. Go to the "Breakpoint navigator", click the "+" button at bottom, the choose the "Exception Breakpoint...". When the crash happen again, Xcode should stop at your exception code.

Comment: I did that, it shows a green breakpoint line at the same place, at the class declarations in the AppDelegate.  I added the photo to the post

Comment: Check the Xcode console window, it logs "Unknown class....". First, you need check if there has a "ProficiencyPart" class in Xcode. If there no "ProficiencyPart" class, you need check your storyboard to find which viewcontroller is "ProficiencyPart", then change the custom class of the viewcontroller to defalt.

Comment: I looked at my storyboard there is something that is a viewController there, my default view controller is set to default though, should I change the class of my storyboard?

Comment: I guess you are using a storyboard from another project.There may be too much errors. You need to fix it one by one. The simple way is create a new storyboard and add new viewcontrollers. Forget about the old project!!!

Comment: okay! Thanks for all the help even though it couldn't be fixed, I did that and the errors are gone.  now just to debug and iron out the functionality

Answer (score 0):

there is an Unreferred Outlet in your ViewController , Right click on your start ViewController and make sure there is no exclamation point in front of Outlets

Answer (score 0):

Go to Build Phases -> Compile Sources, and see whether the app has two "ViewController.swift" files. If yes delete the one which you don't want.

Hope this helps you!